# Ternary Operator in a php print?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am trying to use a ternary operator in a print statement like so:

```
print'<span class="mailbox-attachment-icon"><i class="fa fa-'. $extension == 'zip' ? 'yes' : 'no'  .'"></i></span>';
```

It is breaking my page every time.  I have attempted moving around `'`'s with no luck.  Yes `$extension` is defined.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Order of operations is important. Surround your entire ternary clause with parentheses. It's impossible to know where it ends otherwise. For all we know, those extra closing tags at the end are being appended to the false option of the ternary.

Comment: post answer =P thank you that did it, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is being evaluated left to right. You have to enclose that ternary clause in parentheses to ensure it is evaluated before being appended to the string.

```
print'<span class="mailbox-attachment-icon"><i class="fa fa-'. ($extension == 'zip' ? 'yes' : 'no')  .'"></i></span>';
```

Comment: Will accept as soon as time allows, I appreciate it David.

Comment: Now knowing that I can do what I was thinking =)  `($extension == 'zip' ? '-archive-o' :  ($extension == 'txt' ? '-text-o' : ''))`